# Calling 'rails new demo' created a folder named "new"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed Ruby and Rails using apt-get in Ubuntu. Then when I test my installation, this thing happen.

When I call `rails server` inside a rails-created-folder, rails created a new folder called "server" for me, with a correct folders structure, including `controller` folder, `app` folder, `gemlock` file, etc.

How could it possibly happen? I will try reinstalling RoR, but has anyone  encountered this?

Last time, I used RVM, but whenever I create a new app, I will have to waith for rails to redownload all the bundle file, but in this installation, I don't have to. Can you help me explaining it?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Thank you @shime, I am using rails 3

Comment: make sure you do with `rails -v`, because rails 2 creates new applications with `rails new_app` and rails 3 does it with `rails new new_app`.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, it sounds like your rails executable is rails 2.

1. Try `gem uninstall rails`, select all versions.
2. Run `rails -v`. If this command works you've got a system version of rails that isn't being handled by RVM. BTW, this is why many rails devs are shifting from RVM toward rbenv + bundler.
3. If you still have rails after `gem uninstall`, run `sudo gem uninstall rails`. On RVM, sudo gets to your system gems. You might want to sudo gem uninstall everything, so you don't have this conflict in the future.
4. `gem install rails`, you should get version 3.2.8.
5. Try `rails new my_app` again. It should work. If this doesn't work, try the following:

Create a parent directory for your rails projects, like `~/rails`. Then create a `GEMFILE` that looks like this:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rails', '~>3.2.8'
```

Then inside `~/rails` run `bundle exec rails new app_name`.

If that doesn't work... you've got a bigger system config problem of some kind I guess.

Comment: Which thing ended up solving your problem?

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Here is my ![screenshot](http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa397/bellvietnam/Capture.png).that follows your guide. You are right, there must be something bigger.

Comment: Note: I used sudo apt-get install, no RVM is installed in this one. Thank you

Comment: Be sure to run `sudo gem uninstall rails`. It looks like its a system issue though, so also try `which rails`, see where it's living in your path and go delete it.